# Mock debounce util function using react testing library or jest not using lodash

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library, debouncing

I am trying to mock my debounce util function but coming up short on my coverage. Everything is passing but none of my lines have coverage. I am not using _lodash.

Test.js

```
import { debounce } from '../../data/utils/utils';

afterEach(cleanup);

jest.useFakeTimers();

describe('debounce util', () => {
  const callback = jest.fn();

  beforeEach(() => {
    debounce(callback, 500);
  });

  it('should call debounce util', () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      debounce(callback, 10);
    }
    jest.runAllTimers();
    expect(callback).toBeCalledTimes(0);
  });
});
```

Util.js

```
export const debounce = function debounce(fn, ms) {
  let timer;
  return () => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      timer = null;
      fn.apply(this, arguments);
    }, ms);
  };
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me that you are not testing the debounce functionality correctly. Calling debounce returns a new function. You need to execute the return function. Also you should test that callback is not called before timeout has passed and that it's called exactly once after the timeout has passed.

Here's a modified version of your test:

```
import { debounce } from '../../data/utils/utils';

afterEach(cleanup);

jest.useFakeTimers();

describe('debounce util', () => {
  const callback = jest.fn();

  beforeEach(() => {
    // Reset in case there are more test cases depending on the same mock
    callback.mockReset();
  });

  it('should call debounce util', () => {
    const debouncedCallback = debounce(callback, 10);
    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      // Execute the debounced function
      debouncedCallback();
    }

    // Should not have been called yet since 10ms is not passed
    expect(callback).not.toHaveBeenCalled();

    // Fast forward time => 10ms will be passed
    jest.runAllTimers();

    // Now the callback should have been called exactly once
    expect(callback).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

Comment: When I try to run this test replacing the import with `import debounce from 'debounce-promise';` I get an error saying `TypeError: debounce_promise_1.default is not a function`.